# Why did my pork center cut loin turn out tender but tasteless?

Tags: pork

Why did my pork center cut loin turn out tender but tasteless?

First I marinated the meat for two hours with a mixture of balsamic vinegar, olive oil and Italian seasoning. Then pan-seared it to brown its surface. Finally I braised it in the oven, covered with aluminum foil, using a vegetable sauce, until the internal temperature was 150 F.

The result was a tasteless meat, very tender but with a mushy texture.

Answer (score 3):

Did either your "Italian Seasoning" or the sauce contain salt? If not, then your pork was almost certainly tasteless because it needed salt.